# Relatively Compact definition.

Tags: general-topology, definition

Let $A \subset X$, then $A$ is said to be relatively compact if the closure $cl(A)$ is compact in $X$. Why is this called *relatively* here when it is "relative" to the universal space $X$?

Shouldn't relative compactness mean $A \subset E \subset X$ is relatively compact if $A = E \cap C$ for $C$ compact in $X$.

Answer (score 3):

Being relatively compact is not an absolute property of a space $A$, but of an embedding $A \subset X$ into an ambient space $X$. It would be more precise to say that $A$ is relatively compact in $X$. If $A$ is relatively compact in $X$ and $A \subset Y$ for some other space, it need not be relatively compact in $Y$ (take e.g. an non-compact $A$ and $Y = A$).

In your definition a third space $E$ enters and there are two interpretations.

1) $A$ is relatively compact in $X$ if there exist $E$ and $C$ as above.

2) $A$ is relatively compact in the a pair $(X,E)$ if there exists $C$ as above.

The first interpretation is equivalent to

3) There exists a compact $C \subset X$ such that $A \subset C$.

1) $\Rightarrow$ 3) is trivial, for the converse take $E = A$. Thus, if $X$ is Hausdorff, then $\text{cl}(A)$ must be compact which is the "usual" definition. More generally, the same is true in any $KC$-space $X$ (see https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/KC-space).

The second interpretation makes things complicated by working with a pair $(X,E)$ instead of a space $X$. There are two "extremal" choices for $E$:

a) $E = X$. This means that $A$ is compact.

b) $E = A$. We get nothing else than 3).

a) generalizes to any closed $E \subset X$. In this case $A$ is a closed subset of $C$, hence itself compact.

For any choice of $E$, 2) implies 3). Thus, for a $KC$-space $X$, 2) implies that $\text{cl}(A)$ is compact. The converse may be true for some choices of $(X,E)$, but a) shows that is in general false.

Comment: So then what is "relatively" here mean then? If we just mean compact in the universal space...

Comment: In my answer I discussed three different concepts of "relatively compact": The standard one 0) $\text{cl}(A)$ compact and two variants 1) and 2) of your suggestion. 1) is the same as 3) which agrees with 0) for Hausdorff spaces. 2) does not really give a clear concect because it depends on an additional parameter $E$, but we have $A$ compact $\Rightarrow$ 2)  $\Rightarrow$ 3). Thus, for Hausdorff $X$, 2) is somewhere between $A$ compact and 0). The "real meaning" of being relatively compact (or of any other mathematical definition) is a philosophical question.

Comment: However, in Henno Brandsma's comment you get the motivation for the concept: Each infinite subset of $A$ shall have at least one cluster point in $X$, and all cluster points shall be contained in $\text{cl}(A)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost, I understand that If $A$ is relatively compact in $X$ and $A \subset Y$, $A$ doesn't need to be relatively compact in $Y$. What if additionaly $X \subset Y$ could we then said that $A$ is relatively compact in $Y$? I would say that obvious answer is yes, but I need to be sure 100%. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mark I am not sure. Essentially you ask whether the closure of a compact set is compact. This is trivially true for Hausdorff, or more generally KC, spaces $Y$. There are obvious examples for spaces in which the closure of some compact set is bigger than the original set, and in that case the closure is **possibly** not compact. As an example take a non-closed singleton set in a non-T1-space. But I do not have an example where the closure is not compact. This may be worth a new question.

Comment: @PaulFrost, thank you for the answer. The cases I am interested in are when $X$ and $Y$ are Bochner spaces e.g. $X=C([0,T];H^{10}(\mathbb{R}))$, $Y=L^2(0,T;L^2(\mathbb{R}))$. In this case $X \hookrightarrow Y$ where $\hookrightarrow$ stands for the continuous embedding. So the answer should be yes 100% if I am not mistaken. My question is concerned with the similar one that is connected to tightness and Prohorov's theorem. I will post it in a few days on MSE (even today if I manage it) and I would appreciate your thoughts about it. I will send link to it here in the new comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A set of the form $C \cap E$ where $C$ is compact in $X$ is relatively compact in $E$ (when $X$ is Hausdorff), as $\operatorname{cl}(C \cap E) \subseteq C$ and so is a closed subset of a compact set, hence compact.

If $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ is compact, then we cannot always find such a $C$ with $E \cap C= A$, as that would make $A$ closed in $E$ (again for Hausdorff spaces), and non-relatively-closed sets can also be relatively compact.

So defining relatively compact as you suggests creates a weaker, less useful notion.

Comment: And that means...?

Comment: So how do we actually know then, that making the closure to be compact is the right ingredient for "relatively compact"

Comment: @Hawk the intuition is that every subset of $A$ has a cluster point ( or total accumulation point or subsequential limit) but not necessarily in $A$ ( but then thus in its closure).